# Determining functions types. one - one , onto and bijective

Tags: functions

Could anyone give an idea to start up with this question:

Let $f$ be a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ . How to verify whether it's one to one or onto function?

Comment: For onto, look at the restriction $x \mapsto f(x,1,1)$. For injective, can you find two sets of $(x,y,z)$ parameters such that $f(x,y,z)$ is the same for both?

Comment: For injective , two sets of (x,y,z) can be (2,3,4) and (4,3,2) which will same result of F(x,y,z) = xyz  as it's a product of those three numbers. So, as two different element can have same image in co domain and are not unique so it's not one- to - one. Is that understanding correct or not?

Comment: @KaMal: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$f(1,2,2)=f(2,1,2)$

Since two different inputs for $f$ give the same image, it's not one-to-one.

Since $\text{codomain}=\text{range}=\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is onto.

Comment: I clearly understood the logic behind not being one-to-one . But , could you please elaborate the logic how is it onto?

Comment: A function $f$ is said to be onto if its codomain is equal to its range. Since $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, the domain is $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$. To find out what the range is, we want the set of all images. $xyz$, for $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ can give you any real number, and so we conclude that range is $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\text{codomain}=\mathbb{R}=\text{range}$, we can say that $f$ is onto.